# Android application icon click different behavior

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, launch

I've faced the different behavior of my app while clicking its icon if it was already launched before.

If I install the app via Eclipse or apk manager, launch it, press home button and then launch the app again clicking the application icon - it will bring the first activity from stack to front.

If I install the same version from the Play Market and follow the same steps - the application is relaunched completely from the very beginning (`splash screen activity`).

#### *Is there a difference between intents which are used to start the app in this two cases?*

#### *How can I simulate the Play Market behavior to ensure that everything is fine before the release?*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clear the cache/Data of your application from `settings => App => Clear Cache` and see what happens. However, I noticed that app takes more time when we use Google Play then when we directly use eclipse to run it. The intents are the same for the same application so no differences.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like its to do with the android lifecycle. Read more here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Your activity will go through different stages when it starts back up depending on if it has been completely destroyed or if it has just been stopped. Pressing the home button will only stop your app rather than completely destroying it. If you're phone is running out of resources android might destroy your app in order to free up the resources its using.

Running from eclipse will start your app from a brand new start up (The same as people will get when they install from the market). So if it works when you run it from eclipse. It should work when other people install it too.

Comment: You could also delete user (non-default) data of your Eclipse emulator by deleting **C:/Users/[Username]/.android/Avd/[Device_name]/userdata-qemu.img** . When you launch the emulator it will rebuild the virtual storage from scratch so it will be like installing your Application on a new device